# Is there for all $N$ an integer that is the sum of, say, twenty $N$-th powers in two different ways?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

I believe the following to be true, but I have been unable to find any reference concerning the question.

**Statement** : for every $k\geq 1$, there exists $N = N(k)$ such that there is **no** non-trivial solution in non-negative integers to the equation $$x_1^N + \cdots +x_k^N = y_1^N + \cdots + y_k^N.$$

That is, there is at most one (up to order) representation of any natural number as a sum of $k$ $N$-th powers, for some sufficiently large $N$ with respect to $k$. (I also believe that it should be true for *all* sufficiently large $N$).

I know (from the Wikipedia page on generalized taxicab numbers) that, for $k=2$, it is unknown whether $N=5$ works, but I don't know if it is unknown whether any $N$ works.

Is the statement true, and if yes, how to prove it/where can I find a proof ?

Comment: Sounds like an open question.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, where does this question come from? I remember hearing about it very recently...

Anyways, for sufficiently large $M$, we can always represent $M$ as a sum of $k$ $N$th powers.

Assume all the $x_i$ lie between $1$ and $m$. Then there are $\binom{m}{k}$ different sums of $\sum x_i^N$. But there at most $km^N$ sums, meaning that $$\binom{m}{k}< km^N$$ which doesn't hold for large $m$ - so there are at least two sums which are the same.

Comment: You should think as $k $ being fixed (small, e.g. 20) and $N $ very large, there is no contradiction (the inequality does hold).

Comment: I see no problem. Let $k$ be any positive integer. Suppose there is such a value $N=N(k)$. Then the inequality holds for large enough $m$. The OP's statement did not impose an upper bound on $x_i$. Therefore no such $N$ exists for this value of $k$. But $k$ was unrestricted, so not only is the OP's statement (viz that for every $k$ there is an $N(k)$) false, but it is false for every $k$: for every $k$ there is no $N(k)$. Is this answer wrong? Did I miss anything?

Comment: The inequality does NOT hold for large enough $m$. E.g. $k=2$ and $N=5$.

Answer (score -1):

"OP" inquired about equal sums of around $20$ (nth) power's

in two ways. Well for degree two, Albert Beiler in his book

"Recreations in the theory of numbers" page $159$ has given

a solution for $28$ squares in two ways. The solution is

mentioned below.

[2,18,22,37,38,39,41,43,49,67,72,80,85,103,116,154,164,

175,178,192,200,207,215,222,230,247,422,593] equal to

[13,16,17,23,30,43,47,84,92,93,119,120,142,163,165,167,

177,183,188,199,215,219,261,270,280,363,372,382]

The sum of above is $1030225$ which is a square of $(1015)^2$

From above solution, many more similar solution's can also be

arrived at.

Comment: You give an example for a specific $N $ for which there is a solution but this is not related to my question. I am looking for a $N $ for which there is NO nontrivial solution.